# Watching a single file, in a folder, for modification using watchdog

Tags: python, file-io, monitoring, watchdog, python-watchdog

I am trying to watch a single file for modification in a directory.
This file is 'csv' and is generated by the google form responses. It gets updated as soon as a new response is registered and this new entry needs to be used to create new objects and stored in DB. 
As a test I tried updating a sample .txt file in a directory which contained several folders. To achieve the task I used watchdog and tried logging the modification events for the folder.
The folder structure is as follows

```
-test
  |--a.txt
  |--fileRandom.txt
  .
  .
```

I tried logging the activity using the following code

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    def on_modified(self, event):
        print(f'event type: {event.event_type} path : {event.src_path}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = 'test/wdogfolder'
    event_handler = Handler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=False)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Upon editing **a.txt** I get the following log.

```
event type: modified path : /test/wdogfolder
event type: modified path : /test/wdogfolder/.goutputstream-CP5LX0
event type: modified path : /test/wdogfolder/.goutputstream-CP5LX0
event type: modified path : /test/wdogfolder
```

Now if another file were to be edited inside the same folder then the log is as follows.

```
event type: modified path : /test/wdogfolder
event type: modified path : /test/wdogfolder/.goutputstream-J2YCX0
event type: modified path : /test/wdogfolder/.goutputstream-J2YCX0
event type: modified path : /test/wdogfolder
```

I was hoping of making use src_path to decipher which file changed and thus a simple 'if' statement would have been enough to tackle the problem statement.
But now how do I handle the modification of only **a.txt** since the path doesn't seem to mention the file name which gets modified.
TIA!

**Edit** 
I am working on ubuntu 18.04. The same code seems to work on windows in the expected way. What might the reason behind that be? And how to circumvent this issue?